# How to move all users to a VoiceChannel in JDA and DiscordAPI for Minecraft with Java?

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit, discord-jda

I've been trying to wrap my head around this for a few days now.. I really have no idea why this isn't working. I looked up online to see if I'm missing something but as far as I know everything should be working perfectly. I don't see any errors but the bot just isn't moving anyone.

The API I am using is located here: https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/discord-bot-api-jda.49783/ running on SPIGOTMC 1.16.5

Everything on the bot I made works perfectly but this.

```
public void MoveUsers(boolean toChannel) {
    if(toChannel) {
        //Move players to channel and mute them.
        for(VoiceChannel vc : bot.getBot().getVoiceChannels()) {
            if(vc.getManager() != null) {
                for(Member m : vc.getMembers()) {
                    if(m != null && m.getUser().getIdLong() != 813656916076527688L) {
                        if(channel != null && m.getGuild() != null)
                            botMove(m);
                    }
                }
            }else {
                Main.getInstance().console.sendMessage("...");
            }
        }
    }else {
        //Move players out of channel and unmute them.
    }
}

public void botMove(Member m) {
    Main.getInstance().console.sendMessage(m.getUser().getName());
    
    m.getGuild().getController().moveVoiceMember(m, channel);
    
}
```

In ***botMove***, I print out the username of the person I am trying to move and all of that calls. However the bot itself is not moving the user. Anyone have any solutions to this?

Comment: Try adding a `.queue()` to `m.getGuild().getController().moveVoiceMember(m, channel)`.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use this old JDA version? [See this on how to migrate](https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA/wiki/0%29-Migrating-to-V4#guildcontroller)

Comment: @Danny, THANK YOU SO MUCH! I dont know how I didnt see that!

dan1st, I will go ahead and look into that! Thank you!

Comment: The plugin you linked is using a very outdated version of JDA, I suggest migrating to a newer version of JDA and not using these plugin APIs for minecraft (Which are basically JDA with a few helper methods) and use JDA yourself.

Comment: @MrBorder, yeah Ill go ahead and migrate over to that. I only started using the API cause I believed it was going to be easier but turns out it makes me have to jump through a hunch of hoops.